# Unable to share entire screen

Tags: xorg, screen, sharing, display-manager

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and I tried DWM window manager with the XDM display manager for a weekend but I didn't have the time to adapted to my style because I started classes at the university again. I changed the display manager back to gdm3 and got the usual gnome style for Ubuntu, but after that, I notice I can't share my entire screen when I'm in a video call, I have problems using Discord and Meet, I also notice that I can share only one screen at the time.

I would like to know what to do to fix this problem, I think it has something to do with Xorg and Xserver but I'm not sure about it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you manage already to fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From: [Google Community](https://support.google.com/meet/thread/65557706?hl=en)

1. Edit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
2. Uncomment #WaylandEnable=false
3. sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
4. ctrl + alt + backspace or just reboot

Comment: This doesn't sounds correct.

If you will manually disable WL, isn't better to simple login using Ubuntu Xorg? (you can select it before login)

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
Uncomment #WaylandEnable=false
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
ctrl + alt + backspace or just reboot

this fix the issue but then my screen looks yellowish